# Use PHP to Process an Array in Chuncks

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

Here's an example of the array I need help with (let's call it $MY_ARRAY)

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [NAME] => 1351449606472 [EMAIL] => aaa@yadda.com [ID] => 996774000001224477 ) 
[1] => Array ( [NAME] => 1351449605330 [EMAIL] => bbb@yadda.com [ID] => 996774000001224473 ) 
[2] => Array ( [NAME] => 1351449604318 [EMAIL] => ccc@yadda.com [ID] => 996774000001224469 ) 
[3] => Array ( [NAME] => 1351449603089 [EMAIL] => ddd@yadda.com [ID] => 996774000001224465 ) 
[4] => Array ( [NAME] => 1351449602046 [EMAIL] => eee@yadda.com [ID] => 996774000001224461 ) 
[5] => Array ( [NAME] => 1351449600883 [EMAIL] => fff@yadda.com [ID] => 996774000001224457 ) 
[6] => Array ( [NAME] => 1351449599840 [EMAIL] => ggg@yadda.com [ID] => 996774000001224453 )  
)
```

I know how to step thru this using foreach as follows: (NOTE: edited to show what I'm actually doing at the cost of simplifying the question).

```
$aws = curl_init();
$url = "https://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/";
curl_setopt($aws, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($aws, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//process data
foreach($MY_ARRAY as $X) 
{
    //set-up email
    $MY_ARRAY = $X['EMAIL'];
    $ID = $X['ID'];
    $SUBSCRIBER_ENCODE = rawurlencode($SUBSCRIBER);
    $HELLO = "";
    if (strlen($X['NAME']) == 0)
    {
        $HELLO = "Subscriber,<br /><br />";
    }
    else
    {
        $HELLO = $X['NAME'].",<br /><br />";
    }
    $EMAIL_BODY_ENCODE = rawurlencode($HELLO.$BODY);
    //tune curl vars
    $DATE = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s e');
    $HASH = hash_hmac('sha1', $DATE, $AWSPRI, true);
    $KEYS = base64_encode($HASH);
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = "Host: email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com";
    $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    $headers[] = "Date: ".$DATE;
    $auth = "AWS3-HTTPS AWSAccessKeyId=".$AWSPUB;
    $auth .= ",Algorithm=HmacSHA1,Signature=".$KEYS;
    $headers[] = "X-Amzn-Authorization: ".$auth;
    $MAIL = "Action=SendEmail&Source=".$XROM_ENCODE."&ReturnPath=".$BOUNCE_ENCODE."&Destination.ToAddresses.member.1=".$SUBSCRIBER_ENCODE."&Message.Subject.Data=".$SUBJECT_ENCODE."&Message.Body.Html.Data=".$EMAIL_BODY_ENCODE;
    curl_setopt($aws, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $MAIL);
    curl_setopt($aws, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $resp = curl_exec($aws);
}
//complete log and close curl
curl_close($aws);
```

So what I'd like to is step thru the array three at a time.

Comment: Is this a kind of `BCC` or `CC` ??? or you are trying to call `mail` 3 times

Comment: The actual example is more complicated. I've boiled it down to this example to focus on what I'm not understanding.

Comment: It needs to be three separate emails as each one is personalized: note the Hello ".$X['NAME']

Comment: are you wanting to send the same person (key) 3 emails, or just three emails at a spurt?  -- just read other comments...  so why 3 at the time?

Comment: personalised is one at a time not 3. and for the love of Buddha, don't use mail() for this.

Comment: **"Assume it's just {some code}"** no add the code, you want free help ask the actual question, all this hiding, i just assume you are doing something illegal or immoral.

Comment: @Dagon ... why do i feel the same way ...

Comment: I dont feel that responsibility.  I am not the judge of their morality.  I think it is typically more likely that they are embarrassed to show their coding techniques, or reveal a 'secret' of some type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I think I understand the question enough to answer, if I dont understand the need.  There are probably many ways to do it.  one way may be something like

```
// make array into an array of little arrays
$littleArrays = array_chunk($input_array, 3);
// now we loop through outer array
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($littleArrays);$i++){
    // now we loop through the inner arrays
    for($j=0;$j<sizeof($littleArrays[$i]);$j++){
       mail($littleArrays[$i][$j]['EMAIL'], "Example Subject", "Hello ".$littleArrays[$i][$j]['name']);
    }
}
```

if I understand correctly.  There may be a faster or better way.  I think it is an unorthodox solution because I dont understand why you would send 3 at the time.

note this is not a complete solution...  for example it would shoot an error if the array length was not evenly divisible by 3...

on thinking about this the first comment was the best solution [ARRAY CHUNK - PHP.NET](http://php.net/array_chunk)

EDIT:  solution changed to use array_chunk with simple for loops to navigate them.

Comment: Am not sure how this makes sense ...

Comment: how does it not?  he wanted to step through his array 3 steps at the time right?

Comment: never use mail() for any kind of mass mailing, its very inefficient.

Comment: It looks that way because I'm trying to simplify the problem. If you must know, it's not a php mail execution, it's a curl post to api I'm working with. The api can only accept a few at a time. If I typed out all the curl stuff my question would be diluted to a curl discussion. But thanks for the possible solution!

Comment: @ Dagon --I agree, but that was not the question I think.  I believe the spirit of the question was how to step through his array 3 at the time.  I editted the answer to say that http://php.net/array_chunk is a better solution than the for loop

Comment: @johnwhitney if you going to 'edit' the question to such an extent hiding what your actully doing, theres no point even asking.

Comment: The point is to simplify the question. There are so many posts here with excess stuff that it's hard to understand the root issue. Please give me an example of how to do this with the array_chunk. It's referencing the keys I need help with.

Comment: The documentation at php.net is very complete.  array_chunk will make from your array many small arrays `$little_arrays = array_chunk($input_array, 3); `  Then you have an array of little arrays each of them being 3 items (or less) long.  You loop through the outer array then through the inner arrays.

Comment: There, I changed the code for you to incorporate array_chunk.